# JQ widgets Get the position when moved the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the position of a window when it's opened like this:

```
$('#windowAdConsole').on('open', function(event) {

    $('#windowAdConsole').jqxWindow('bringToFront');

    xPosPrev = xPosNew;
    yPosPrev = yPosNew;
```

//Here I get the position

```
        $('#windowAdConsole').jqxWindow({ position: { x: xPosPrev + 20, y: yPosPrev + 20} });
    position = $('#windowAdConsole').jqxWindow('position');
    xPosNew = position.x;
    yPosNew = position.y;


});
```

But when I moved and release the position, I don't get the position moved but the inicial position when it's opened. For example the inicial position of the window is x: 200 y:200, then I moved it and I get again the same values.
The code used to moved it is:

```
    $('#windowAdConsole').on('moved', function (event) {
    position = $('#windowAdConsole').jqxWindow('position');
    xPosNew = position.x;
    yPosNew = position.y;
});
```

How can I get the new moved position of the window?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
$('#windowAdConsole').on('moved', function (event)
{
  $("#showevent").html("You  moved the window " + ', X: ' + event.args.x + ', Y: ' + event.args.y);
});

....
<div id="showevent"></div>
```